# Importing styl file in different folder in Meteor

Tags: meteor, stylus

Using Meteor + Stylus, how do you import a file in another folder starting from the root?

Given:

/css/colors.styl
/home/home.styl

I know I can use `@import '../css/colors'` but it gets messier the deeper it goes. Is there a way to do something like `@import '/css/colors'`?

Comment: How deep is your CSS hierarchy?

Comment: I put each template/html, js, and css in their own folder. If a template has a sub-template I create a folder for the sub and in turn it will have its own html, js, and css files. So it can get deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in meteor 1.2, you can import a `.styl` file relative to your application's root directory with the following syntax:

```
@import '{}/client/imports/colors.styl'
```

See the [package documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/stylus) for more details. Also note:

> The package processes all `.styl` files, treating `.styl` as entry points and all files with extension `.import.styl` or a file in under an `imports` folder as an import.

So putting your imports under a directory with `imports` in the name is a good idea.